# How can I insert data from a online table in excel using Selenium for python 3.7?

Tags: selenium, automation, python-3.7

I was asked to create an automation tool to create a report excel sheet using the data from an internal web page of the company I work for. I selected python(3.7) as my language(since most of my coworkers use it as well)and Selenium to do the job. Once I have clicked and filled all the fields using Selenium to filter the data I need, I got at least 60 pages of 20 rows each one(the number can vary), so I have to copy each page data in an excel sheet and click the 'next' button, copy the data again and so on, until all pages are processed. I was able to copy the data for the first page of the web site, but when I try to do the 'next' process, it fails in saving the data in the excel sheet. Here is the code I'm working with

```
    ***Bunch of Selenium steps***

def excelFactory(values, row, col): #fuction to create the excel workbook
    fname = 'App_Report.xlsx'

    if os.path.exists(fname): #check if the workbook is already created
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
            ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
    else:                     #create the workbook if not found
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
    ws.cell(row= row, column= col).value = values #insert the data from the online web in the 
                                                  #workbook 
    row = row + 1
    wb.save(fname)

def dataDownload(): #function to parse thru the online table and read the data
    data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rowNumber")
    for td in data:
        values = td.text
        print(td)
        excelFactory(values, row, col)
        NxtButton = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('NxtButtonClassName')
        for content in NxtButton:
            if content.text == 'Next':
                content.click()
                dataDownload()

dataDownload()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? can you post the complete stack trace & the html source?

Comment: hello, i'm not getting any error, the code is just not saving the data. I cannot provide the html source since is a internal web page from the company. I might get trouble with cyber sec department

Comment: Just consider some alternatives. Seeing that it's an internal site, if you could get access and permission, it would be a lot better to query the source system database directly. Alternatively, you could write the data from selenium to a text file with .csv, then open it in excel and save as .xlsx